# Approval Process Customization

Tags: apex, visualforce, approval-process, approval-step, approve-action

I have a requirement where the approver can send the record back to submitter to Rework as well besides Approving or Rejecting. Records can be Approved, Rejected or sent back for Rework. How can `approval processes` be customized to achieve this ?

Comment: this is approval proccess' native functionality.

Comment: can this be customized / enhanced to include one more status like Rework.

Comment: you can give rejected reason but i am not sure if you can add status rework. although you can update some field and set status to rework.

Comment: ok, so the approver will reject the approval request and final rejection action will do a field update on the record associated to approval process so that a custom field on it will say something like Sent back for Rework. In Approval History related list it will be visible as Rejected. I think it is not possible to display Rework there.

Comment: yes it is not possible to display it there